# "This application requires a java runtime 1.8" when using wine

Tags: linux, java, wine

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.14.16-arch1-1
- Java: java-8-openjdk
- DE: Xfce 4.16

When trying to launch .exe file with **Wine** on my Arch Linux I get this error: `This application requires a java runtime 1.8`.
The problem is that I already have this version of java installed under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java`.

I do have `jre8-openjdk` package installed on my system.

These are all my Environment Variables (output of `$ printenv`): https://pastebin.com/tAh4XEec

The output of `$ archlinux-java status`:

```
Available Java environments:
  java-17-openjdk
  java-8-openjdk (default)
```

The output of `& java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

There is also an issue with .jar file of the same program not opening, although it might be a problem with this specific program. Nothing happens when I try opening it with what presumably is installed Java 8. Although, when I try to open it with Java 17 it gives this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rksct.jpg

`$ java Elician.jar` ouputs `Error: Could not find or load main class Elician.jar`

Both .exe and .jar executables can be downloaded here: https://elician.ru/start

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please edit the question and include any necessary code/environment variables from external sources in the body of the post [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) The reason being that if the [external link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430) ever expires, both question and answers would loose their value and stop being reproducible.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691070/cannot-install-jdk-8-on-wine-ubuntu) should help you.  We won't be downloading any linked executables by the way.

Comment: To run a jar from commandline you need `[/path/to/]java -jar jarfile` -- note the flag `-jar`. I don't know for arch which could be different, but _most_ OpenJDK builds don't include javafx; only _Oracle_ did that, and only in 8, hence the advice in your error box.

Comment: I suspect its looking for a *windows* version of java...

Answer (score 1):

`[/path/to/]java -jar jarfile` worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please don't use answers to ask questions. You should instead edit the question and expand it or ask a new question.

Comment: Sure, no problem <3